# Selecting all people with the max age?

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I want to get values from a row with the largest certain value (in this example, the oldest member)

```
Select * from members where age=max(age)
```

Will this work?

And what will happen if there is more than 1 oldest members with the same age?

(I don't have to worry about it because I use auto_increment, but I just got curious)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use auto-increment on age?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * 
from members 
where age = (select max(age) as max_age from members);
```

If there are more than 1 member with the same maximum age, you will get multiple results. To select just one from that:

```
select * 
from members 
where age = (select max(age) as max_age from members);
limit 1
```

You can optionally add an `order by` if you favor any particular data over a random one.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You want

```
 Select * from Members 
 where Age = (Select Max(Age) from Members)
```

If, as suggested by your mention of autoincrement, you are looking for the last inserted ID in a table, you want

```
 Select LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: Assuming you want to have this a big query with a group by, does that mean you'd have to nest these two queries?

Answer (score 2):

This will not work since this is `Invalid use of group function`, better use `SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a single **SELECT** statement, if you use **GROUP BY** and a **@variable** to find and store what is min/max value and filter matches with **HAVING** at the end.

Presuming you have a table **members** with at least two columns: **id** and **age**, then you can use a statements like this:

```
SELECT id, age, @max:= IF(@max > age, @max, age) FROM members GROUP BY id HAVING(age = @max);
```

or

```
SELECT id, age, @min:= IF(@min < age, @min, age) FROM members GROUP BY id HAVING(age = @min);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return only one row - even if more than one members have the same maximum age:

```
SELECT *
FROM members
ORDER BY age DESC
LIMIT 1 ;
```

This (and @podiluska's answer) will return all of them:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM members AS m
  JOIN
    ( SELECT MAX(age) AS max_age
      FROM members
    ) AS allm
    ON allm.max_age = m.age ;
```

Comment: Table names are case sensitive.

Comment: @vearutop: That depends on the settings.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a more contrived way of doing the same:

```
SELECT * FROM members m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM members m2
    WHERE m1.age < m2.age )
```

This query is portable to most databases, works for auto-increasing PKs and also with multiple people having same age. Plus, at least in SQL Server, most of the times will be faster than the version using a subquery (especially if [members] has an index over column [age]).

Answer (score 0):

select * from customers where age=(select max(age) from customers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).