# Return all rows with the "MAX" value in SQL?

Tags: mysql, max

I have the following table:

Table: Scores
What I have:

```
+----+-------+
| Id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   300 |
|  2 |   300 |
|  3 |   300 |
|  4 |   100 |
|  5 |   200 |
+----+-------+
```

What I need:

```
+----+-------+
| Id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   300 |
|  2 |   300 |
|  3 |   300 |
--------------
```

How would I grab "all" the top scores id 1, 2, 3 in SQL.  I started off using MAX (in mysql) but that only returns one row.

Comment: Do you want just the top 3 scores?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115044/selecting-the-max-value-in-sql?rq=1

Comment: @João Where 3 should be x in [0, n) ..

Answer (score 55):

```
SELECT Id, value
    FROM Scores
    WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM Scores);
```

Comment: @RidingRails: Glad to help. Please remember to up vote the answers you've found helpful and accept one so that this question does not remain "open."

Answer (score 8):

Use a quick variable:

```
SELECT @max := max(value) from scores;
SELECT id, value FROM scores WHERE value = @max;
```

or else: (and I am normally in staunch opposition to sub-queries, but this one's a no-brainer.

```
SELECT id, value FROM
scores
INNER JOIN (Select max(value) as value from scores) as max USING(value)
```

Note that these are both preferable to the more basic `WHERE value = (*subquery*) because for each of them, the query to find the MAX value is executed exactly once (the absolute guarantee of this is why I prefer the variable-based solution). With the subquery version (in the WHERE, not the JOIN), that query is likely to be executed once *per row*.

I have done some query analyzing with `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`, and the INNER JOIN method is probably the most succinct and optimal of all suggestions (supposing that you are in an environment where using MySQL variables is too cumbersome; I still think it is the cleanest).

## performance:

Since some interesting discussion took place, I decided to really dig in and evaluate these things (overkill, I know, but fun and useful knowledge on bigger issues). There is a bit of an analysis trick for detecting full table scans; adding `WHERE (@foo := @foo + 1)` to the subqueries in question, then setting @foo to 0, running the query, and seeing what @foo is. It's not the end-all be-all query-toll metric, but it can be quite informative about how often you are asking MySQL to evaluate each row. Here are the "scores" with your sample data (lower is better):

- @ctrahey (both): 5 (scans once to find MAX)
- @Joe Stefanelli: 25 (scans once *per row* (5*5))
- @Jocelyn : 17 (I can't explain this one, but I would love to learn why :-)

Comment: In your second example, there's no column named `value` in your subquery for the `USING` to operate on.

Answer (score 6):

In MySQL you need to do this with a join or subquery:

```
select *
from t
where value = (select max(value) from t)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this query:

```
SELECT id, value
FROM Scores
WHERE value>=ALL(SELECT value FROM Scores)
```

Documentation: [Subqueries with ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html)

[Optimizing Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimizing-subqueries.html):

> MySQL enhances expressions of the following form with an expression
>   involving MIN() or MAX(), unless NULL values or empty sets are
>   involved:
>
> ```
> value {ALL|ANY|SOME} {> | < | >= | <=} (uncorrelated subquery)
> ```
>
> For example, this WHERE clause:
>
> ```
> WHERE 5 > ALL (SELECT x FROM t)
> ```
>
> might be treated by the optimizer like this:
>
> ```
> WHERE 5 > (SELECT MAX(x) FROM t)
> ```

Comment: This won't work. You've hard-coded your LIMIT to match the sample data provided. It will fail if there are fewer or more rows with the max value.

Comment: Yeah, that won't do.  It works on my simplified example table in the question.  The answer above and below work.  Thanks!

Comment: This will cause a magnitude of comparisons to occur where only one (per row) is necessary. See the above +1'd answers for a slight modification with very significant optimized execution (comparing for equality once to MAX() instead of inequality for each), make sense?

Comment: @ctrahey: run `EXPLAIN` on the query and you will see you are wrong. MySQL detects the use of the keyword `ALL` and optimizes the execution.

Comment: So, help me understand (I always desire to learn). When I lok at the extended output of your queries `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`, I still see a sub-query in there (this is post-optimizer, btw). When I do the same with my JOIN version, I see an equality comparison to a static value (300 with the OP's sample data).

Comment: Here is your query (less the SELECT portion) post-optimizer: `from \`test\`.\`scores\` where <not>((\`test\`.\`scores\`.\`value\` < (select max(\`test\`.\`scores\`.\`value\`) from \`test\`.\`scores\`)))`

Comment: and here is my JOIN suggestion's: `from \`test\`.\`scores\` where (\`test\`.\`scores\`.\`value\` = '300')`

Comment: fwiw, I removed my -1 in good faith; 'cause I like good discussion; Is there something for me to learn about why this is more optimized than I think it appears to be?

Comment: Interesting. Check out the performance metric I added to my answer. All the other queries have "simple" mathematical relationships between the total number of rows and the number of row-evaluations in the sub-query. Yours, however, does not. It's quite curious (it does perform *better* than the other sub-query suggestions, btw :-)

Comment: I tried to add to my answer the result of two `EXPLAIN`, for comparison purposes. But I failed to format the output properly. I will try again tomorrow.