# How to find most expensive items in sql with more than one most expensive item?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, max

I have more than one items with the highest price on my database and I would like to know how to return the most expensive items with the highest price on my database, without using LIMIT.
I have tried using

```
SELECT MAX(price) FROM items
```

but it only returns one item with the highest price (I have two items with the highest price).

The schema of my database is

```
items (itemID: integer, description: string, price: integer)
```

Comment: Try this 
                                                                                                           SELECT itemID, price
    FROM items
    WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM items); Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167809/return-all-rows-with-the-max-value-in-sql

Comment: What is wrong with using limit if you want certain number of records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a join to fetch them all like so:

```
SELECT I.* FROM Items I JOIN
   (SELECT MAX(price) AS maxprice FROM items) M
   ON I.price=M.maxprice;
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work.

```
SET @p1 := (SELECT MAX(price) FROM items);
SELECT * FROM items WHERE price = @p1;
```

Using variables, `p1` stores the maximum `price` from the table `items` and then uses the variable `p1` in the following query to return all records which have that maximum price without limiting the number of records as you desired.

Comment: This is probably the right way to go, and should run faster than my solution.  It avoids any messiness with derived tables.

Comment: @peterh Sorry I couldn't make you laugh today - I tend to be to the point. I have, however, updated the solution with an explanation of how it works. Cheers.

Comment: Hi your code returns an error when I run it: Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error @mseifert

Comment: I would expect a bit more to the error code. Let me know if there is any more to it. It should work. What interface are you using (phpmyadmin?). I've created the tables and tested the code using phpmyadmin with success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this mate:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE itemID IN (
   SELECT itemID FROM items
   WHERE price IN (
      SELECT MAX(price) FROM  items
   )
);
```

or this

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE price IN (
   SELECT MAX(price) FROM items
);
```