# having more than one MAX value

Tags: mysql

[I create this using the following:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz9gP.jpg)

```
SELECT genre, count(movie_id) FROM movies_genres
GROUP BY genre
ORDER BY count(movie_id) DESC;
```

My goal is to have the genre of movies that appears the most, which is the first two genres. 
I searched around, and most answers use "LIMIT 1", but I think it won't work in this case.
I tried MAX() but I don't know how to display the genre column then.

Please advise, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return all rows with the "MAX" value in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167809/return-all-rows-with-the-max-value-in-sql)

Comment: @GurV OP wants *all* the max values. That can be any number of rows.

Comment: @Sherry what are the columns you need in final output? can multiple genre for same movie id?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT genre,count(*) 
FROM movie_genres 
GROUP BY genre
HAVING count(*) = (
  SELECT count(movie_id) 
  FROM movie_genres 
  GROUP BY genre 
  ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to find max of count and then use having clause to get all the genres with that count.

```
select genre
from movie_genres
group by genre
having count(movie_id) = (
    select max(cnt)
    from (
        select count(movie_id) cnt
        from movie_genres
        group by genre
    ) t
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this give all values you want? First create a collection ids what you want. Then use `WHERE IN` to get the output you want

```
SELECT genre FROM movie_genres
WHERE movie_id IN (
    SELECT max(movie_id) FROM movies_genres
    GROUP BY genre
)
```